# JavaFX - how to increase Canvas drawing of 10K - 15K polygons

Tags: canvas, javafx-8

I need to draw from 10K to 15K polygons 30 times per second on JavaFX Canvas. I made the different Thread which creates new Canvas object, draw everything it needs and replace Canvas in Application UI thread by this one. But unfortunately it works slow because of drawing polygons by invoking method

```
graphicsContext.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, len);
```

Is there any way to increase the speed of drawing?

So the drawing Thread:

```
public class RMapFXView implements Runnable {
private final static int FPS = 30;
private final RMapModel mapModel;
private final RMapController controller;

public RMapFXView(RMapModel mapModel, RMapController controller) {
    this.mapModel = mapModel;
    this.controller = controller;
}

private Canvas draw(){
    Canvas bufCanvas = new Canvas(controller.getWidth(), controller.getHeight());
    GraphicsContext context = bufCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    //getting the objects to draw
    Map<Integer, List<RObject>> visibleLayers = mapModel.getVisibleObjects();
    MBR mapMBR = mapModel.getVisibleMBR();

    for (Integer i: visibleLayers.keySet()){
        List<RObject> layer = visibleLayers.get(i);
        for(RObject o: layer){
            int start = o.getStartPoint();
            int end = o.getEndPoint();
            double[] xPoints = new double[end - start + 1];
            double[] yPoints = new double[end - start + 1];
            //filling the xPoints and yPoints, setting the fill color, stroke color and so on
            if (o.isClosed()) {
                context.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
            } else {
                context.strokePolyline(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
            }
        }

        context.fillText("" + layer.size(), 10, (i+ 2) * 10);
    }

    return bufCanvas;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //replacing current canvas
        controller.setMapCanvas(draw());
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        long sleepTime = (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)/FPS) - (endTime - startTime);
        if(sleepTime > 0)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(sleepTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

}

Machine and JVM options:

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using platform text rasterizer
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
Direct3D initialization succeeded
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9 device
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 8192
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
OS Information:
    Windows 7 build 7601
D3D Driver Information:
    Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 //tried on different machine with ATI Radeon 45XX - the same situation
    \\.\DISPLAY1
    Driver aticfx32.dll, version 8.17.10.1119
    Pixel Shader version 3.0
    Device : ven_8086, dev_0166, subsys_17F4103C
    Max Multisamples supported: 4
 vsync: true vpipe: true
```

Comment: Scene graph or a MeshView might work better for this than Canvas. Can you add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question? Also try the latest [JavaFX dev release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and include info on your OS and runtime hardware (processor and GPU).

Comment: Added the mcve. If I comment the fillPolygon and strokePolyline methods invocation everything works fast so the problem is in drawing speed. Thanks for suggest, I'll try.